# Is there a way to disable this link when the Sum_Total is Zero and enable when it is greater than Zero?

Tags: javascript, php, html, laravel

I am trying to disable the href link when the {{$sum_price_total}} is zero and enable the link when the sum total is greater than zero. Also, if it is possible, I will like it to echo a message when it is disabled like "please add item."

**HTML**

```
  <div class="Item">
       <h4>Grand Total <b><span> ${{ $sum_price_total }}</span></b></h4>        
        <a class="btn btn-default" style="background-color:#ff4f81 !important; color:#fff;" href="{{ url('/customCheckout') }}">Checkout</a>
    </div>
```

**I HAVE TRIED THIS**
I have tried using the code below it disable the link, but it is not what I want. I want the link to be disabled if the {{$sum_price_total}} is zero and be enabled when {{$sum_price_total}} is greater than zero.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

I will be glad to get help or suggestion on this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [if else condition in blade file (laravel 5.3)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40122633/if-else-condition-in-blade-file-laravel-5-3)

Comment: ^ Sorry, not a laravel user, not sure if the template is this blade thing... Anyway, you just want an if/else conditional statement. Don't use the anchor `<a>` tag in one representation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with `PHP` in `blade`.

You can directly use **@if** in **blade** file

```
<div class="Item">
       <h4>Grand Total <b><span> ${{ $sum_price_total }}</span></b></h4>        
        <a class="btn btn-default" style="background-color:#ff4f81 !important; color:#fff;" @if($sum_price_tota > 0) href="{{ url('/customCheckout') }}" @endif>Checkout</a>
    </div>
```

Comment: Awesome bro thanks.....If there a way i can show like a tooltip with a message if it is disabled?

Comment: just put `@if($sum_price_tota > 0) href="{{ url('/customCheckout') }}" title="disabled" @endif`